# "Helping others IN some fields" vs "helping others AT some fields"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Would you like to gain experience in helping others **in** some fields which you think you like?

vs

> Would you like to gain experience in helping others **at** some fields which you think you like?

Or maybe something other will be better than "in" or "at"?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether ***field*** is singular or plural, figurative or literal, or qualified by a word like ***some***. The [only preposition that normally occurs](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=works+%2A+my+field&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworks%20in%20my%20field%3B%2Cc0) before ***field*** is ***in***.

Comment: The construction **at some field** is likely to be used only in contexts such as: **He was spotted exercising his dog at (or **on**) **some field on the far side of town.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use *at* here, because a field is something you work *in*, have experience *in*, and so on. See the examples here:

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/field_1#field_1__15